# Azure App services for android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have been looking now for two days help how to get started with Mobile Apps for android in Azure, but all documents are about Mobile service.

If I have understood correctly, they are different thing. Could somebody point where I can find some examples or even the SDK documentation. Or is it really so that Microsoft haven't got it done because it doesn't need Microsoft products to implement applications.

Comment: Did you find anything about this or no?

Answer (score 0):

So azure doesn't make mobile apps per se, Azure can just provide you a mobile backend service known as Azure Mobile services. 
With Azure mobile services you can create a server side backend, with database and API's which are consumed using Windows/android/ios SDK for azure mobile services. This backend is not only scalable but also provides features like Offline & Sync, authentication and Push Notification backend support.

client SDK's and Mobile Services Samples - https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services
A lot of resources, samples and videos are available here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/

Have fun building...

Comment: so you didn't read what I wrote or was it just so wrong said? if you haven't noticed the mobile service is OLD system and new applications should be build to use app services. I think they are not using same SDK.

oh and I very well know what is back-end and what its for... I have been doing programming for last 20 years

Comment: you are right, anybody reading that q will understand that you are somehow trying to find how to make android apps in azure which i pointed  out that azure doesn't  but azure mobile services (you are right here, that its called app services now) is just a back-end service. Please rephrase the question, what is i that you exactly want.